# Change column value status to be interrupted if no new record return after 10 mins

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have three tables ,scadainfo_online, scadainfo_limit and scadainfo_status, data populated just like their name, self-described.

[image: er diagram]

My purpose is changing automatically "status" column's values in scadainfo_status if no new record get in scadainfo_online values in 10 minutes. there is a one-to-one relationship using column item_id.

So, how can I do it? Google told me about a job with about 30 seconds interval, is there another answer? Thanks.

Comment: Is data_time a timestamp?

Comment: yes, date_time is a type of date .it‘s’ wrong in the er diagram

Comment: Do you mean to update the scadainfo_status table when there are NO updates in scadainfo_online within 10 minutes or no updates for a particular item within 10 minutes. If it's per item then can you confirm if the ITEM_ID is supposed to be unique or do you know its the same item using a different column ?

Comment: absolutely, and item_id is unique

Comment: A quick scenarion - I have an item_id 1234 in scadainfo_online with a status record of 'OK'. You want to change the status record for item_id 1234 if no new record for that item_id has been received in the last 10 minutes. As item_id is the primary key you will never be able to write another record for 1234 to the scadainfo_online table. I think you either don't quite understand the problem yourself or perhaps are just not communicating it clearly enough. Have a think about what you really mean (which may be very close to what you have now) and update to show that. Clarity is everything.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your response to my comment above this may be what you want. Or it may at least show you the principle of what you want.

```
UPDATE scadainfo_status ss
SET ss.alarm_status = 'NO UPDATE'
WHERE ss.item_id IN (WITH updates
                       AS ( SELECT so.item_id AS item_id,
                                   COUNT(*) 
                                      OVER (PARTITION BY item_id
                                            ORDER BY date_time 
                                            RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND NUMTODSINTERVAL(10,'MINUTE')FOLLOWING)-1 AS later_records
                              FROM scadainfo_online so)
                       SELECT item_id
                         FROM scadainfo_online
                        WHERE later_records <1)
```

The 'IN' sub-query is counting records for the id that have occurred between this row and any that are in the following 10 minutes. A row (the current row) is returned if there are no further rows.
Sorry about the description of how it works; I find analytic queries tricky and explaining them even more so.